# Membership provider Reset password to Custom Formatted password

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Membership provider ResetPassword method , resets a password that contains a lot of non alfa numeric chars.

The question is if its possible to change the default password creation template to lets say Numbers Only ?

Comment: Have you tried changing the password format regex?

Comment: This is what is referred by Basic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.passwordstrengthregularexpression.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick that worked for me was :

1. Reseting the password and getting the new password , then using the new password calling method ChangePassword that will accept new generated password on my own choice , if anyone can suggest something less tricky will appreciate.